# E2E tests for web component based applications

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-component, e2e-testing, shadow-dom

Web components promise to be "the next big thing" in the web. I like the approach, but I wonder how to write end-to-end tests (ui tests). I do not talk about testing the component itself in isolation.

With Selenium WebDriver API it's not possible to access the shadow-dom. You have to rely on JavaScript and this circumvents a copule of the WebDriver features like checking if the element you interact with is visible/accessible.

I looked at Vaadin TestBench and they nearly don't use the mature WebDriver API anymore, but completely rely on JavaScript. They even have to emit chnage or blur events by hand.

I do not think web components have a bright future if writing of e2e tests is that hard. Opinions?

Comment: *If you have a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail*. Does  E2E include testing the inner workings of the VIDEO Element? Or a DIV for that matter? If you look at WCs as something not-React to build applications, then yes, you need testing. If your WCs are 'atoms' / 'micro-services'  that do what they do then you do not have to test them.. **again**... I do not test my hammer... I do not test my keyboard.. I do not test my IDE... I do not test my car... I do test the brakes on my motorbike every ride.

Comment: I agree with Danny. For Acceptance or system tests a Web Component should be treated as a black box. Your unit tests should test the internals of the Component. With Selenium  you should only need to test the interface and not the internals. If that doesn't work then you may need to adjust what you expose with the component's interface.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, several testing libraries aid in piercing the Shadow DOM, including Playwright, documented [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors/#selecting-elements-in-shadow-dom).